# referencing VisualBasic methods

Tags: vb.net

In VB, I want to assign a (shared) **method to a variable**
And I'm asking if there is some **namespace operator** like `::` in C++ and Java

```
Class C
    Public Shared Function m(a as Integer) as Integer
        Return  a * 2  
    End Function
End Class
                
Public Sub Main()
        
    Dim localM As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = C.m
        
    Console.WriteLine(localM(5))
End Sub
```

I know I could use `function(a) C.m(a)`
but that is not pretty
and I don't want to create a new function every time
and is also sensitive to argument changes

as for why would I do that
I'm actually passing it to function as an argument
(`someFunction(3, C::m)`)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/

Comment: I actually just solved it by making methods into attributes (`Func(of Integer, Integer)`). But the question still stands, as this will not always be an option

Comment: That's not an attribute, Func is a delegate.  It is always an option.

Comment: @HansPassant how is it not an attribute if it is an object representing function? But never mind names. It is **not** always an option, as I can't change classes that I didn't create. I still don't know how to use the Delegate to pass the method as an argument.

Comment: I understood delegates. The key is to use `addresof`.

Comment: A rose by any other name... except [`Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) already has a very specific meaning in the .Net world that is different from how you used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Sub Main() 
    Dim localM As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = AddressOf C.m
    Console.writeline(localM(5))
End Sub
```

You can see it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uxl0Y7

I didn't change anything in the sample class, except to complete the function so it returns a value (required for the function to compile) and to fix your lousy capitalization.

---

> I'm actually passing it to function as an argument

In that case:

```
Sub Main() 
    Dim localM As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = AddressOf C.m
    Foo(localM)

    ' Or

    Foo(AddressOf C.m)
End Sub

Sub Foo(theMethod As Func(Of Integer, Integer))
    Console.WriteLine(theMethod(5))
End Sub
```

---

In either case, the trick is to do two things:

1. Define either an `Action` (for a `Sub`) or `Func` (for a `Function`) that matches the signature of the target method. In this case, it's `Func(Of Integer, Integer)`. Any method up to 8 arguments can be mapped this way, but you do have to know the signature in advance.
2. Use `AddressOf` to capture the reference to the method.

Comment: `AddresOf` keyword/syntax was what I was looking for

Comment: You're missing an `s` in there, and it's the second time you've done that. Computers expect you to be more precise than that.

Comment: They actually don't, since there is autocomplete/Intelli sense. That is also why I didn't bother much with capitalization at first (but I corrected it)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Class C
    Public Shared Add1 As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = Function(value As Integer)
                                                          Return value + 1
                                                      End Function

End Class
```

to use

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim foo As Integer = C.Add1(3)
    Debug.WriteLine(foo)
End Sub
```

**edit**

```
Class C
    Public Shared Add1 As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = Function(value As Integer)
                                                          Return value + 1
                                                      End Function

    Public Shared DebugStr As Action(Of String, String) = Sub(first As String, second As String)
                                                              Debug.WriteLine("One-{0}  Two-{1}",
                                                                                first, second)
                                                          End Sub

End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim foo As Integer = C.Add1(7)
    Debug.WriteLine(foo)

    C.DebugStr("Quick", "Fox")
End Sub
```

Comment: That is how I solved my problem. Though the question is how to access methods that are not `Func`. Because I will not always be able to manually change a method to `Func`

Comment: @Superior - if not a function then a Sub so try Action?  See edit.

Comment: I cannot always change class implementation. So it is not about is it a sub or function.